# VirtualBox No Internet Win7 Host, OS X Guest

Tags: macos, network, internet, virtualbox

I have set up Mac OS X 10.9 in a Virtual Machine and I'm struggling to get any internet connection. In my network settings (Mac), it says I'm connected but nothing works. Safari doesn't load any page, AppStore doesn't load anything (all greyed out).

In VirtualBox, the only settings that showed any connection at all within the VM was Bridged Adapter with an Adapter Type of `Intel PRO/1000 MT Server`.

What can I do to get a connection going within the VM?

Comment: You need to be asking this question on an OSX86 site. OS X is not licensed for virtualisation on anything other than Apple hardware, & is off-topic for SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also perhaps your router is not working

Comment: @Mark My router works completely fine. If it didn't, I wouldn't be able to make this comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Virtual box try changing the connection mode to NAT instead of Bridge.

If NAT works than there is some issue with DHCP Server or Router that assigns the IP address to your network.

Comment: NAT doesn't work. I've tried all of them.